# Where I must put the token id?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, security, asp.net-web-api

I'm developing a Web Api using asp mvc web api. For Authenticate a user the api implements a token system authentication, so the user must to send a extra parameters on the request that it is a key value pair: token:key.

My Question is if I do a Post request to the api I must send the token on the content body or I can sen it on the url(e.g. miurl.com?token=aaaaaa)

thank you

Answer (score 1):

I would sent the token as an HTTP Authorization header. This is considered more "standard" for REST/HTTP. It is defined in the HTTP standard:

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

The reasons why it is better are

- Placing it in the URL exposes it in the browser history etc.
- Using the message body means you must read the entire message body in order to authenticate it whereas using the header means you only need to read the header.

To extract the token and perform authentication/authorization, you could implement a custom `AuthorizeAttribute` and read the token from the `HttpContext` by overriding the `AuthorizeCore()` method.